# Where to ask "of which alloy is this tool forged"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question is:

> I need to know the material from which a broken allen wrench is
>   forged, because this will let me buy another, more sturdy allen wrench
>   with high-tensile materials, and to know which material
>   breaks under this amount of force.
>
> I suspect the material is chrome vanadium, a common steel alloy used
>   in tools. I can provide pictures of the broken inside; I can measure
>   it's weight and volume, and thus its density.

Is this suited for Chemistry.SE, or for another site?

Comment: How about http://diy.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: By looking at the questions, they are home-improvement oriented. Mine is not for the home.

Comment: I've improved your question's grammar and formatting: I suspect English may not be your first language, even if it is, I still hope you appreciate my changes.